# How can I remove border on JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

So I am trying to start a graphics program, where I have a JFrame that holds multiple JPanels. The JPanels need to combine to create 1 image, however when I run my program I see borders around the images. I cannot quite distinguish if the border is caused by the JLabel that holds the image or if it is because of the JPanel or because of the Layout Manager.

*How can I remove the border? Would i need to change the layout manager? If so how?*

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StarryNight {
    JFrame backGround;
    JPanel rootPanel;
    JLabel rootImage;

    public StarryNight(){
        backGround = new JFrame("Starry Starry Night");
        backGround.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        backGround.setResizable(false);
        backGround.setSize(1000,667);
        backGround.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        backGround.setLayout(new BoxLayout(backGround.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        rootPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.setSize(1000, 667);
        rootPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);;
        rootImage = new JLabel();
        rootImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Starry Night.jpg")));
        rootPanel.add(rootImage);


        JPanel jap = new JPanel();
        jap.setSize(1000,100);
        jap.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        backGround.add(rootPanel);
        backGround.add(jap);
        backGround.pack();
        backGround.setVisible(true);


    }

    private static void runGUI()    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        StarryNight ssn= new StarryNight();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, a JLabel does not have a border by default. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Don't set sizes. Let the images, components and the layouts set the sizes for you. This could be your problem -- hard to tell since we don't have the images with us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> rootPanel = new JPanel();

By default a JPanel uses a `FlowLayout` which defaults to allows 5 pixels before/after components. So when you add our image to the panel you will see 5 pixels of space on all sides.

If you don't want that space then look at the FlowLayout API and create a FlowLayout without spaces between the components and then add that layout to the rootPanel. Something like:

```
rootPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(...) );
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. I was able to remove the border by 
rootPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0) );